# WPF Mutate Command Pattern

Tags: wpf, command-pattern

Should I mutate the parameter passed to the Execute method on ICommand?  If not, what is the best way to change the State of the application, or View Model, after a command is invoked?

**Thoughts**

The Command Pattern invokes a method on an object, in the case of WPF it's the model or view model.  This requires the model to know how to perform the action on itself.  We've all seen and used the RelayCommand implementation.  The problem I have with this is that it's difficult to swap out behaviors.  It's also difficult to find a place to put that "special case" code.  What if I want to show another view?

I like the idea of creating a Command for each Use Case.  I would have a concrete class that implements ICommand that handles the logic for executing the use case.  This requires a reference to the model just like the Command Pattern.  The difference is that the action logic would be outside of the model and thus be mutating the model passed in as a parameter.  Let's look at some sample code.

I have a window that shows a list of the ubiquitous Person object.  We want to invoke a command on a Person that clears their name.  MainViewModel has a collection of Person objects called People.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <commands:ClearNameCommand x:Key="ClearNameCommand"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Here is my list box that is bound to the collection and displays each person with a button to clear their name.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Name" Width="100"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Width="100"/>
                    <Button Command="{StaticResource ClearNameCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Content="Clear"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Below is the Execute method on the concrete class ClearNameCommand.  It displays a dialog box asking if they want to perform the action.  I think this proves as a good example of why you wouldn't put this command in the model.  Also imagine that you had to log somewhere that the name was cleared?  Undo Redo maybe??  Where does all this code go??!!

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Person p = parameter as Person;
        if (p != null)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show(
                "Are you sure you want to clear the name?", 
                "Clear Name", 
                MessageBoxButton.YesNo, 
                MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                p.Name = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

I suppose you could leave all of the preparation code in the command and then call a Clear method on the Person.  However, I'm still not convinced that is the best way.  What if clear changes?  You end up with Clear2 and Clear3 and so on.  Not to mention a method for every possible use case or maybe even more.

**Some More Thoughts**

So let's say I have a View Model with a reference to a Model that allows pass-through Data Binding or it wraps the Model all together.  What I want to get away from is creating a Command property on the View Model for every single use case.  Also, what is so clean about that design?  You're still mutating the Model object in the Execute method.  I don't think I'm bending the Command Pattern all that much.  My Window is the Client.  The Model is the Receiver.  And the Button is the Invoker.  The only difference is you're injecting the dependency with the invoker.

To rephrase my question slightly, does anyone see any red flags for doing this?

I found this while researching the command pattern.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc984279.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea what you're talking about... you seem to have a very... er, unique way of working with `Command`s.

> This requires the model to know how to perform the action on itself.

A model class should never have `Command`s in it... instead, put them in whichever view model that displays that model class.

> ... it's difficult to swap out behaviors

Again... what? Don't 'swap out behaviours'. A `Command` shouldn't change its functionality. Just create one for each function.

> It's also difficult to find a place to put that "special case" code

What is "special case" code?

> What if I want to show another view?

Each view should have its own view model. Each view model should have its own set of `ICommand` objects. It's really not a problem if you have to duplicate a little `Lambda` expression in a `RelayCommand`.

> imagine that you had to log somewhere that the name was cleared? Undo Redo maybe?? Where does all this code go??!!

View model, view model, view model.

> I suppose you could leave all of the preparation code in the command and then call a Clear method on the Person

What do you think the difference would be between calling `p.Name = ""` and calling `p.ClearName()` which did the same thing? No difference, or at most, it would take fractionally longer calling the method than setting the property directly.

> What if clear changes? You end up with Clear2 and Clear3 and so on

Once again... what??? How would `Name = ""` change?

While I hope I answered *some* of your questions, I think that I *must* have misunderstood you in some way because I don't fully understand your question. Please feel free to ask further questions, but please add them as an edit to your question and I will reply in this answer, so that the comments don't get ridiculously long.

---

UPDATE >>>

In response to the first two comments:

Yes... in almost all cases, I would have one view for one view model. And no, I have absolutely no problem with changing the value of *anything* from a `Command`. I can't think of any reason why you would think that that is not OK. Imagine this scenario:

You have a list of objects and an edit panel in the UI that the user can use to edit the objects. You also have a `Button` with a `Command` that is named `Duplicate`. Now, by definition, that `Command` is going to 'mutate' as you call it, a data object, or model class.

It would create a new object and set its properties dependant on the values of the currently selected object. Are you suggesting that this `Command` is somehow wrong for doing this? In my opinion, that vast majority of `Command` (or method) functionality will 'mutate' some property or properties of the data objects in the view... how else do we provide this useful functionality?

And to continue with the 'where should this be?' question... where else can it be? In the view model, we have access to the currently selected item *and* the whole collection of items. From the view model, we can have access to any number of services that provide all kinds of functionality for us. You'd find it hard to connect with some of these things from your separate `Command` classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'll have to clarify the question a bit I suppose.  Are one of those guys who creates View Model for each Model?

Comment: So just to clarify, you didn't see anything wrong with mutating the Model within the command, whether the command was a RelayCommand on the ViewModel or a concrete class??

Comment: Thank you Sheridan.  I'm not way out in left field here.  I think it was a legitimate question.  It's generally frowned upon to alter an object passed as a parameter.  It's not found in any GoF patterns.  Not even the command pattern.  The Command property in WPF doesn't really follow the command pattern as it is.  I definitely see the value of using Commands on the view model.  I use them all the time.  I just think there are times where we would create a concrete command class.  Maybe to add functionality at runtime.